# How to set AppleScript Entitlements for Finder?

Tags: xcode, macos, applescript, sandbox, entitlements

I need to use an AppleScript in my app with enabled sandbox. Just using things like "tell Finder to bla-bla-bla". Very simple. I got that I need to make a record for finder in Entitlements something like this:

```
<key>com.apple.security.scripting-targets</key>
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.mail</key>
    <array>
        <string>com.apple.mail.compose</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

Is anybody know the correct entitlements record in Xcode for Finder? I've try to use next option:

```
<key>com.apple.security.scripting-targets</key>
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.finder</key>
    <string>com.apple.finder</string>
</dict>
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Finder does not support `scripting targets` so you need to use previous temporary exception.

```
<key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events</key>
<array>
   <string>com.apple.finder</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Yep, I tried it too. For some reasons AppleScript doesn't work. This is my entitlement file:
`<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
 <true/>
 <key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events</key>
 <array>`
    <string>com.apple.finder</string>
 </array>
</dict>
</plist>`

I try to run next script:

`tell application \"Finder\" \n restart \n end tell`

But nothing happens :-(

Comment: Sorry for inline code :-)  How to set a line break in here?

Comment: `Restart` is actually part of `System Events` and is passed-through to the Finder. Try to use `System Events`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works great now!